Virtual Box with ubunru arm64

[
Пытаюсь запустить виртуалку ubuntu arm с VirtualBox, но почему то не хочет запускать iso образ, на последнем крине если выбрать iso, перезапускается машина и выходит тоже самое. устанавливал Hyper-V там примерно такая жен ошибка, другая машина amd64 Debian установилась, а arm64Debian нет, alpine linux тоже не запускается. Процессор хеон е5 2420, в биосе нет ничего про virtual technology. Хост Windows10

хеон это не arm, было бы странно ожидать на нём работоспособности arm-программ

ну хеон это и не amd ведь

хеон использует архитектуру amd64 (которую компания Intel лицензировала у компании AMD для использования в своих процессорах, такие дела)

Виртуальные машины не обеспечивают эмуляцию процессорной архитектуры, отличной от хостовой. Вам нужен эмулятор, например qemu.
